# Configure git to always prefix branches with user name

Tags: git, shell, alias

I have the following alias in my .gitconfig `br = checkout -b`, so `git br feature` creates and checks out a branch called `feature`

The behaviour I would really like is for `git br feature` to create a branch `wheresrhys/feature` though.

How can I use concatenation to create the desired name within a git alias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running git from a Unix-like shell, the common trick is to use a shell function in your alias definition. Adding the following in your `.gitconfig` will do what you want.

```
[alias]
    br = "!f() { git checkout -b wheresrhys/$1; }; f"
```

Regarding the bang or exclamation point, the `git config` documentation notes

> If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command. For example, defining `alias.new = !gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD`, the invocation `git new` is equivalent to running the shell command `gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD`. Note that shell commands will be executed from the top-level directory of a repository, which may not necessarily be the current directory.